# Powershell: Where method or where-object can't find data in my custom array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get data out of my created array which I created using "openfiles" but it doesn't find anything. I think it's caused by the way I created this array. Here's what I did:

```
    $searchstring = read-host "Please provide the path or filename"    
    $query        = openfiles /query /S SERVERNAME /FO CSV /V
    $queryrenamed = $query.Replace(C:\Localpath\,X:\) #Replace the given FileServerinformation with the user mapped network drive for better visibility
    $result       = $queryrenamed | ConvertFrom-CSV | sort -Property "Open File (Path\executable)" | Select "ID","Accessed By","Open Mode","#Locks","Open File (Path\executable)" | Where-Object {$_."Open File (Path\executable)" -like "*$searchstring*"} | format-table -AutoSize
$result
```

So far so good, I get a nice formatted result. But now as I want to use the $result to find/extract matching IDs like:

```
$result.Where({ $_.ID -eq 10000})
```

it doesn't find it.

If I do a "select" also nothing:

```
PS C:\> $result | Select "ID","Accessed By","Open Mode","#Locks","Open File (Path\executable)"


ID                          : 
Accessed By                 : 
Open Mode                   : 
#Locks                      : 
Open File (Path\executable) :
```

And if I do a "select *" I get this:

```
$result | Select *


ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280
pageHeaderEntry                         : 
pageFooterEntry                         : 
autosizeInfo                            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.AutosizeInfo
shapeInfo                               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo
groupingEntry                           : 

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3
shapeInfo                               : 
groupingEntry                           : 

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df
groupingEntry                           : 

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c
groupingEntry                           :
```

I could create a new $result2 with the modifications, but I think this is not very efficient.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Remove `| format-table -AutoSize`

Comment: `Format-Table` shouldn't be there :)

Comment: haha so easy, nice! Thanks guys